# Making a http request using CEFSharp and all its stored cookies

Tags: cefsharp

I'd like to make a webrequest to facebook or authenticated site using the cookies already contained in cefsharp after the user has logged on.

How can I do that? I'm currently using HttpWebRequest. Can I somehow retrieve cookies from CEF and pass it to HttpWebRequest? Tried looking at CEFRequest but it's not accessible nor do I know how to use it

I need all this in order to prefetch resources needed by 2000 sites that I need precached. If you can suggest another way to do that please recommend that as well

Comment: , can you share code if you were able to do this please. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Cef.VisitAllCookies()` will issue a callback for each cookie. You can then selectively include some or all of these cookies in web requests that you make using `HttpWebRequest`.

https://github.com/ataranto/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/CefSharp.h#L122